# Is it possible to bind the value of one textbox control to another textblock control?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.5

I have two datagrids in mainwindow with two seperate datacontext. Have to bind the value of one column in datagrid2 to column in datagrid1.

Can this be acheived without using elementname binding?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is if you are using mmvm pattern to bind your view with viewmodels then you can use mediator pattern to update your textbox controls. You can check the below link of how it can be done

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/The-Mediator-Pattern-c2c07b54